# Python: extracting text from strings using a key phrase

Tags: python, string, key

Struggling trying to find a way to do this, any help would be great.

I have a long string – it’s the Title field.  Here are some samples.

```
AIR-LAP1142N-A-K
AIR-LP142N-A-K
Used Airo 802.11n Draft 2.0 SingleAccess Point AIR-LP142N-A-9
Airo AIR-AP142N-A-K9 IOS Ver 15.2
MINT Lot of (2) AIR-LA112N-A-K9 - Dual-band-based 802.11a/g/n
Genuine Airo 112N  AP AIR-LP114N-A-K9 PoE
Wireless AP AIR-LP114N-A-9  Airy 50 availiable
```

I need to pull the part number out of the Title and assign it to a variable named ‘PartNumber’.  The part number will always start with the characters ‘AIR-‘.

So for example-

```
Title = ‘AIR-LAP1142N-A-K9 W/POWER CORD’
PartNumber = yourformula(Title)
```

`Print (PartNumber)` will output `AIR-LAP1142N-A-K9`

I am fairly new to python and would greatly appreciate help. I would like it to ONLY print the part number not all the other text before or after.

Comment: Try looking in to regex. `import re`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def yourFunction(title):
    for word in title.split():
        if word.startswith('AIR-'):
            return word

>>> PartNumber = yourFunction(Title)
>>> print PartNumber

AIR-LAP1142N-A-K9
```

Answer (score 3):

What you’re looking for is called regular expressions and is implemented in the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html). For instance, you’d need to write something like :

```
>>> import re
>>> def format_title(title):
...     return re.search("(AIR-\S*)", title).group(1)
>>> Title = "Cisco AIR-LAP1142N-A-K9 W/POWER CORD"
>>> PartNumber = format_title(Title)
>>> print(PartNumber)
AIR-LAP1142N-A-K9
```

The `\S` ensures you match *everything* from `AIR-` to the next blank character.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sensible time to use a [regular expression](http://recompilermag.com/issues/issue-0/beginning-with-regular-expressions/). It looks like the part number consists of upper-case letters, hyphens, and numbers, so this should work:

```
import re
def extract_part_number(title):
    return re.search(r'(AIR-[A-Z0-9\-]+)', title).groups()[0]
```

This will throw an error if it gets a string that doesn't contain something that looks like a part number, so you'll probably want to add some checks to make sure `re.search` doesn't return `None` and `groups` doesn't return an empty tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You may/could use the `.split()` function. What this does is that it'll split parts of the text separated by spaces into a list.

To do this the way you want it, I'd make a new variable (named whatever); though for this example, let's go with `titleSplitList`. (Where as this variable is equal to `titleSplitList = Title.split()`)

From here, you know that the part of text you're trying to retrieve is the second item of the `titleSplitList`, so you could assign it to a new variable by:

```
PartNumber = titleSplitList[1]
```

Hope this helps.